# Why does newgrp change my PS1 and how to prevent it?

Tags: shell, solaris, prompt, group

I have a customized PS1 to show several parameters.  When I switch to a different group using `newgrp`, it switched my PS1 to default ($) and that is annoying.  The default remains even when I switch back to my default group from the changed group.

Any way to stop it from doing that and just keep the PS1 I set in my .profile?

```
>uname -a
SunOS he2unx207 5.10 Generic_147440-19 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-880
```

Of course, if I resource my .profile after newgrp, the PS1 gets correctly applied but I am annoyed because newgrp effectively cancels what was set in .profile.  Why can't it just change the effective group I am associated with without changing other settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you export `PS1`, then the value shouldn't be reset. From the Solaris [newgrp manpage](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/newgrp-1.html):

> Any variable that is not exported is reset to null or its default
>   value. Exported variables retain their values. System variables (such
>   as `PS1`, `PS2`, `PATH`, `MAIL`, and `HOME`), are reset to default values unless
>   they have been exported by the system or the user. For example, when a
>   user has a primary prompt string (`PS1`) other than $ (default) and has
>   not exported `PS1`, the user's `PS1` will be set to the default prompt
>   string $, even if newgrp terminates with an error. Note that the shell
>   command export (see `sh`(1) and `set`(1)) is the method to export
>   variables so that they retain their assigned value when invoking new
>   shells.

Alternatively, you can pass the `-` flag to `newgrp` to reinitialise the environment as if you had just logged in.

Comment: coincidentally, i noticed that my PS1 in fact was not  being exported -- must have been a moment of absentmindedness as i normally always export all the vars set in my .profile.  it works, thanks.